# pointwise convergence and convergence in $\ell_{1}$ norm

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, pointwise-convergence

Assume that we have a sequence $\{\mathbf{x}_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of non-negative vectors in $\ell_{1}$, i.e. $x_{n,i}\geq 0$ for all $n = 1,2 \dots $ and $i= 1,2 \dots $. Next, assume that for any $i$ we have
$$
x_{n,i} \to a_{i}
$$
and $||\textbf{a}||_{1} = b >0$.

**The statement:** $\mathbf{x}_{n} \to \textbf{a}$ in $\ell_{1}$.

I have the following **proof**, but I am note 100 % sure:

Let's fix some $\delta>0$. Then there exists $M$ such that
$$
\sum_{i\leq M}a_{i} \geq b - \frac{\delta}{2}.
$$

Since $\mathbf{x}_{n}$ converges to $\mathbf{a}$ pointwise, then there exists $n_{1}$ such that for all $n\geq n_{1}$ we have
$$
\sup_{i\leq M}|x_{n,i} - a_{i}| \leq \frac{\delta}{2M}.
$$
From those two inequalities above, it follows that $\sum_{i\leq M}x_{n,i} \geq b - \delta$, for all $n\geq n_{1}$.

Therefore, using inequalities above, we have
$$
\sum_{i}|x_{n,i} - a_{i}| = \sum_{i\leq M}|x_{n,i} - a_{i}| + \sum_{i>M}|x_{n,i} - a_{i}| \leq \sum_{i\leq M}|x_{n,i} - a_{i}| + \sum_{i>M} x_{n,i} + \sum_{i>M}a_{i} \leq \frac{\delta}{2} + \delta + \frac{\delta}{2} = 2 \delta
$$
holds for all $n\geq n_{1}$, which proves the oroginal statement.

**edit:**
I see the problem now. In order to have the last inequality, we must also have that $||\textbf{x}_{n}||_{1} = b$, for all $n$.

**hypothesis:** I think, the statement is also true when we just have $\sup_{n}||\textbf{x}_{n}||_{1} < \infty$

Comment: $x_{n,i}$ and $a_i$ are just numbers, so $\|x_{n,i}-a_i\|_1$ doesn't make sense. You need to show that $\|x_n-a\|_1\to 0$. Thus you need to show $\sum_i|x_{n,i}-a_i|\to 0$.

Comment: it was a typo. I hope it is better now.

Comment: A counterexample for your hypothesis would be the following. Let $a_i = 2^{-i}$ so that $\|a\|_1 = 1$. Let $\mathbf{x}_{n,i} = a_i$ if $i \neq n$ and $a_i+1$ if $i=n$. Then $\mathbf{x}_n \to a$ almost surely componentwise, but $\|\mathbf{x}_n - a\|_1 = 1$ for all $n > 0$. However, $\|\mathbf{x}_n\| = 2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Did the book tell you to prove this, or was it "prove or disprove"? If the former the book's hugely wrong; if the latter you should _state the problem correctly_!

Comment: I haven't seen this in any book, the problem just came to my mind and I tried to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your edit, the proof will be correct if $\|\mathbf{x}_n\|_1 = b$ for all sufficiently large $n$. However, there is a more general condition under which it will hold:

Suppose that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\sup_n \sum_{k=N}^\infty |\mathbf{x}_{n,k}| < \epsilon.$$

(I believe this is the $\ell_1$ analogue of uniform integrability). Then your proof works if we also assume $M$ is large enough that the above equation holds for $\epsilon = \delta$ and $N = M$.

**Edit:** This is actually necessary and sufficient. Suppose $\{\mathbb{x}_n\}$ does not satisfy the condition above. Then there must exist some $\epsilon > 0$ and sequences $n_i,N_i \to \infty$ such that $\sum_{k=N_i}^\infty |\mathbf{x}_{n_i}| > \epsilon$ for all $i$.

Then $x_{n_i}$ cannot converge to $a$. To see why, let $M$ be large enough that $\sum_{k=M}^\infty |a_k| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\mathbf{x}_{n_i,k} - a_k| \geq \sum_{k=M}^\infty |\mathbf{x}_{n_i,k} - a_k| \geq \sum_{k=M}^\infty |\mathbf{x}_{n_i,k}| - \sum_{k=M}^\infty|a_k| > \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Since this holds for infinitely many $i$ (all $i$ such that $N_i > M$), $\mathbf{x}_n$ does not converge to $a$ in $\ell^1$.

Comment: do you mean $\sup_n \sum_{k=N}^\infty |x_{n,k}| < \epsilon.$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've updated it.

Comment: btw, is this condition also necessary?

Comment: Yes. If uniform integrability fails, then the sequence $\{\mathbf{x}_n\}$ does not converge to anything in $\ell_1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. Suppose $a_1=1$ and $x_{1,n}=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Let $a_i=0$ and $x_{i,n}=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $2\leq i\leq n$. For $i\geq n$ let $x_{i,n}=0$. Clearly $x_{i,n}\to a_i=0$, and $\|a\|_1=1>0$. However, for any $n\in \mathbb N$
$$\|x_n-a\|_1=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=2}^n1=\frac{n-1}{n}\to 1.$$