# convergence of dominated sequence in $\ell_{1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Assume that we have a sequence $\{\mathbf{x}_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of non-negative vectors in $\ell_{1}$, i.e. $x_{n,i}\geq 0$ for all $n = 1,2 \dots $ and $i= 1,2 \dots $. Next, assume that for any $i$ we have
$$
x_{n,i} \to a_{i}
$$
and $||\textbf{x}_{n}||_{1} =||\textbf{a}||_{1} = 1$. Then, as was shown in [convergence in $\ell_{1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4073665/pointwise-convergence-and-convergence-in-ell-1-norm), the whole sequence $\textbf{x}_{n}$ converges to $\textbf{a}$ in $\ell_{1}$.

Next, consider non-negative sequence $\textbf{y}_{n}$, such that $y_{n,i} \leq x_{n,i}$ for all $n = 1,2 \dots $ and $i= 1,2 \dots $. Also, assume that $\textbf{y}_{n}$ converges to $\textbf{a}$ pointwise. **The proposition:** sequence $\textbf{y}_{n}$ converges to $\textbf{a}$ in $\ell_{1}$.

**Attempt:**

Let's fix some $\delta>0$. Then there exists $M$ such that
$$
\sum_{i\leq M}a_{i} \geq 1 - \frac{\delta}{2}.
$$

Since both $\mathbf{x}_{n}$ and $\mathbf{y}_{n}$ converge to $\mathbf{a}$ pointwise, then there exist $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$ such that for all $n\geq n_{1}$ we have
$$
\sup_{i\leq M}|x_{n,i} - a_{i}| \leq \frac{\delta}{2M}.
$$
and for all $n\geq n_{2}$ we have
$$
\sup_{i\leq M}|y_{n,i} - a_{i}| \leq \frac{\delta}{2M}.
$$

It follows that $\sum_{i\leq M}x_{n,i} \geq 1 - \delta$ for all $n\geq n_{1}$, and $\sum_{i\leq M}|y_{n,i} - a_{i}| \leq \frac{\delta}{2}$ for all $n\geq n_{2}$.

Next
$$
\sum_{i}|y_{n,i} - a_{i}| = \sum_{i\leq M}|y_{n,i} - a_{i}| + \sum_{i>M}|y_{n,i} - a_{i}| \leq \sum_{i\leq M}|y_{n,i} - a_{i}| + \sum_{i>M} y_{n,i} + \sum_{i>M}a_{i}.
$$
Next, since $0<y_{n,i} \leq x_{n,i}$, then for all $n>\max(n_{1},n_{2})$ we have
$$
\sum_{i\leq M}|y_{n,i} - a_{i}| + \sum_{i>M} y_{n,i} + \sum_{i>M}a_{i} \leq \frac{\delta}{2} + \delta + \frac{\delta}{2} = 2 \delta
$$

Therefore, we have shown that for any $\delta>0$ there exists $n$, such that
$$
||\textbf{y}_{n} - \textbf{a}|| \leq 2 \delta,
$$
which proves the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct in my opinion.

Maybe as an intermediate step it would be nice to explicitly mention
$\sum_{i>M} x_{n,i} \leq\delta$,
so that it will be easier to see why
$\sum_{i>M} y_{n,i} \leq\delta$ holds.